# php files(Symlink) are displaying as text

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7, symlink, plesk

This is not same other question like "php file is displaying text or not executing".

In my case, the php files are indeed working fine. However the files(symlink) to the php files are not working.

For example, the normal .php files are working.

```
# ls -al 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 ftomd psacln           9 Jul 21  2010 ystalyfera -> index.php
lrwxrwxrwx    1 ftomd psacln           9 Jul 21  2010 ystradgynlais -> index.php
```

As you can see in the above, the websites is custom coded and all internal pages are symlink to main index.php file. These symlink files are not working and displaying as text files.

The same script working on another server(migrated from there) with Apache 2.2 and php 5.3.

New server has Apache 2.4 and php 5.4(dso), CentOS 7 with Plesk 12.5

Am i missing something?.

Any suggestions?. Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks
Abdul

Answer (score 2):

```
ystalyfera -> index.php
ystradgynlais -> index.php
```

I think the root of the issue is that these files (symlinks) without extension. And standard apache configuration containt something like this

```
<IfModule  mod_php5.c>
    #
    # Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
    #
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
```

Must be

```
ystalyfera.php -> index.php
ystradgynlais.php -> index.php
```